# SSRS connection to Oracle database

Tags: reporting-services, oracle11g, sql-server-2012, ssrs-2012

I know that there are many sources on the Internet on how to do that, but non of them is exact.

Can anybody write clear steps on what have to be done (downloaded, together with links) to connect to oracle database from `SSRS`, and where to find connection string names from `Oracle`.

Using:

```
SQL Server 2012

Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition
```

[image]

for example, this link https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/834305, says that I have to install `oracle client tools`, I typed that in Google, and brought me to this page http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html, I've chose my OS type and downloaded the file, unzipped it, tried to run exe files, but non of them runned. Maybe I don't have to run exe files, or where should I put that folder?

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps:

1. Download the right Oracle client (based on your Operating System) from following link http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html
2. After installing it, navigate to `<Installed_Location>/app/<user_name>/product/client/network/admin`
3. Open the tnsnames.ora file and add the entry (example given below)

   ```
   ORA12DB =
    (DESCRIPTION = 
      (ADDRESS_LIST =
        (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.1.0)(PORT = 1521))
      )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = ORA12)
    )
   )
   ```
4. To make sure you have installed the client properly and set the right entry in tns file, please do the following:

   (i) Open command prompt

   (ii) Type tnsping ***ORA12DB***

   (iii) Hit Enter key

   (iv) You should see a successful message that says; tns adapter is able to resolve the alias. OK.
5. Once all the above steps are performed, provide that same alias name (in the above example, it was ***ORA12DB***) in "Connection String" in the SSRS.